# terminal command for listing available shells

Tags: command-line

I need to check out which shells are available. Which command gives me available (installed shell like, tcsh, csh, bsh) shells in terminal?

Comment: Good answered some time ago in Unix and Linux: [How to find list of available shells by command-line?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140286/40596)

Comment: @steeldriver: I've asked A.B. to delete his answer so you can answer...  Could you answer already so deeplue can switch the acceptance to yours so we can get out of this mess and clean up the comments here?  ;-)

Comment: @fabby http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157889/is-posting-someones-comment-as-an-answer-okay/157912#157912 If you make a comment you make a comment and take the risk of someone else making an answer. Question is good. Answer is good. And the answer was created within a few minutes of the comment. The only thing I see wrong here are the comments.

Comment: @Rinzwind My opinion differs.  I'm talking about basic politeness here.  You should always refer to the original poster and tell them that they should answer the question.  I even have a canned comment for that. (see next comment)

Comment: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: If the original commenter then doesn't want to answer and defers to you, then yes, you're allowed to answer. (And I always do this with new users that need the rep)  **;-)**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open a terminal and run this command:

```
cat /etc/shells
```

Sample output:

```
% cat /etc/shells
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
/bin/ksh93
/bin/tcsh
/usr/bin/tcsh
/usr/bin/fish
/usr/bin/tmux
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run this command:

```
chsh -l
```

Sample output:

```
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/fish
/bin/fish
/usr/bin/git-shell
/bin/nu
/usr/bin/nu
```