# At what point is the ~/.bashrc file created?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

For instance, if I were to run the command `adduser test`, is the .bashrc created automatically upon creation of the home directory for the user `test`? If it's not created upon user creation, under what conditions is it created?

Also, if I add a .bashrc file to the home directory of a user, will it be overwritten by the OS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just tried it, you would find out much faster than by asking here.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In most cases, the initial user files (including `.bashrc`) are created when the user is created. They are copies of the files stored into the 'skeletal' directory, named `/etc/skel`. There are two main commands:

- [**`useradd`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man8/useradd.8.html) is the back-end command, if you using it directly (without any options) just a system user (and its group) will be created:

  ```bsh
  $ sudo useradd new-user
  $ ls -la /home/new-user/
  ls: cannot access '/home/new-user/': No such file or directory
  ```

  - `useradd` will create a home directory and populate it with a copy of `/etc/skel` if the `-m` `--create-home` option is supplied. Thanks for [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971836/at-what-point-is-bashrc-created?noredirect=1#comment1557240_971846) to @jwodder.
  - The option `-s` `--shell` will change the name of the new user's login shell. No matter what the new user's login shell is, the entire content of the 'skeletal' directory `/etc/skel` will be populated into the new user's home directory.
  - A different 'skeletal' directory cold be defined with the `-k` `--create-home` option.
  - The configuration file of this command is `/etc/default/useradd`.
- [**`adduser`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man8/addgroup.8.html) is user-friendly and interactive front-end of *`useradd`*. This command will copy the files from `/etc/skel` to the user's `$HOME` directory by default:

  ```bsh
  $ sudo adduser new-user
  Adding user `new-user' ...
  Adding new group `new-user' (1002) ...
  Adding new user `new-user' (1002) with group `new-user' ...
  Creating home directory `/home/new-user' ...
  Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
  Enter new UNIX password:
  Retype new UNIX password:
  passwd: password updated successfully
  Changing the user information for new-user
  Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
          Full Name []: New User
          Room Number []:
          Work Phone []:
          Home Phone []:
          Other []:
  Is the information correct? [Y/n]

  $ ls -a /home/new-user/
  .   ..   .bash_logout   .bashrc   .config   examples.desktop   .profile   .Xdefaults
  ```

  - The configuration file of this command is `/etc/adduser.conf`.
  - The default value for the new user's login shell is deteminated by the variable `DSHELL=`. It could be specified also via the option `--shell`. No matter what the new user's login shell is, the entire content of the 'skeletal' directory `/etc/skel` will be populated into the new user's home directory.
  - The `SKEL=` variable in this file specifies the default directory containing 'skeletal' user files.
  - The option `--no-create-home` will force the command `adduser` to do not create a user home directory, respectively the content of the 'skeletal' directory will not be copied.
  - If called with one non-option argument and the `--system` option, `adduser` will add a system user... A home directory is created by the same rules as for normal users. The new system user will have the shell `/bin/false` (unless overridden with the `--shell` option), and have logins disabled. **Skeletal configuration files are not copied.** *...from the manual page.*

---

Additionally, when the user is created with any GUI tool as [**`User Accounts`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVCRK.png), the result is identical to that of the command `adduser`.

---

References:

- [What is the difference between adduser and useradd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345974/what-is-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd)
- [What's the difference between "adduser" and "useradd"?](https://superuser.com/questions/547966/whats-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd)
- [Home directory not being created](https://askubuntu.com/questions/374870/home-directory-not-being-created)
- [AddUsersHowto - Ubuntu Documentation Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto#Command-line)
- [What is the *nix command to view a user's default login shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059067/what-is-the-nix-command-to-view-a-users-default-login-shell)
- [Terminal command for listing available shells](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625601/terminal-command-for-listing-available-shells)

Comment: `useradd` will also create a home directory and populate it with a copy of `/etc/skel` if the `-m` option is supplied.

Comment: Your second code block still uses `useradd` in the command; was that supposed to be `adduser`?

Comment: Also, _User Accounts_ makes use of `adduser`, doesn't it?