# .bashrc and .bash_profile not created with adduser but created with useradd

Tags: command-line, users, bashrc, adduser, useradd

I am adding a user named 'test' in my Ubuntu 18.04 server. When I add the user using `adduser`, like this:

```
sudo adduser --system --group test --shell /bin/bash
```

all goes well, I can login fine, but .bashrc, .bash_logout and .bash_profile are not made by default in the home dir. Whereas when I added the user using `useradd` like this:

```
sudo useradd -m test -s /bin/bash
```

the user is added in the same way as `adduser` and I have a preconfigured .bash_profile, .bashrc and .bash_logout in the home dir.

Can someone explain why is there a difference ? Am I missing any flag in `adduser` usage ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior of `adduser` is due to the option `--system`. With this option you are create a system user, with UID under 1000. From [`man adduser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/adduser.8.html):

> If called with one non-option argument and the `--system` option, `adduser` will add a system user... A home directory is created by the same rules as for normal users. The new system user will have the shell `/bin/false` (unless overridden with the `--shell` option), and have logins disabled. **Skeletal configuration files are not copied.**

The *skeletal configuration files* are these files, located in `/etc/skel`, that are copied do the user's home directory when a new normal user is added to the system.

If you want to add a normal user, by default, you do need to add any options to `adduser`, just use:

```
sudo adduser username
```

On the other hand, if you want to create fully qualified normal user by `adduser` you need to add few additional options, for example `-m` to create user's home directory and copy the content of `/etc/skel`.

Read also: [At what point is the ~/.bashrc file created?](https://askubuntu.com/q/971836/566421)

Comment: Oh, my bad I didnt read the manual correctly. Got it, thx !