# Shell shows nothing until key is pressed

Tags: bash, xfce4-terminal

So apparently I did something to my shell (bash) xfce4-terminal, so that everytime I open one al I see is black. I copied my .bashrc over from another computer. when I press Return I get my prompt and everything works as expected. What did I do and how can I fix this behaviour?

thanks in advance

Comment: You mention you "copied your .bashrc" over. First thing to do will be to inspect that .bashrc file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [At what point is the ~/.bashrc file created?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971836/at-what-point-is-the-bashrc-file-created)